# How to access check box, pop up button, radio group, etc. in Object Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am a fairly new user of Xcode (v5.1.1) and I have noticed that when I open an existing or new project the object library on the right displays many more available objects (including check box, pop up button and radio group....see picture).  When I select my storyboard (or .h or .m files for that matter) to use these objects, the object list then disappears and the usual list of objects appear (starting with ViewController, TableViewController, etc).  Is there an easy way to access this first list of objects (to avoid creating custom objects perform the same functions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first list of objects are only available for the Mac platform. If you are doing iOS only then once you click on the storyboard it will show all available objects for that platform.

It is probably a bug in Xcode that allows you to see them in the first place.